# innershadow in react native : style correct on iOs but wrong on Android, why?

Tags: react-native, shadow, react-native-stylesheet

I'm trying to achieve a style on my react Native App and it work's well on iOs but completely miss it on android. Here is the screen of the results :

On ios :

[image: on ios]

On Android :

[image: on android]

(don't mind the icon which is not here there, but it is out of the simulator and the rest look the same)

Here is my code :

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={onPress}
      style={[
        styles.container,
        {backgroundColor: '#F5F5F529'},
      ]}>
      {image ? (
        <Image
          source={image}
          style={{height: Layout.SV_38, width: Layout.SV_38}}
          resizeMethod="auto"
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      ) : (
        <Icon
          name={icon ?? 'help'}
          color={iconColor && iconColor}
          size={Layout.SV_35}
        />
      )}
      <VerticalSpacing />
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.title,
          {color: backgroundColor ? WHITE : Colors.TEXT_COLOR},
        ]}>
        {title ?? 'no title available'}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

and associated styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    //   flex: 1,
    // backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: Layout.SV_5,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    shadowColor: '#00000025',
    shadowRadius: Layout.SV_5,
    shadowOpacity: 2,
    zIndex: -1,

    borderRadius: Layout.SV_15,
    height: Layout.SV_160,
    width: Layout.SV_110,

    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: Layout.FSV_13,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

I've got a warning on iOS but nothing on Android :WARN  (ADVICE) View #2109 of type RCTView has a shadow set but cannot calculate shadow efficiently. Consider setting a background color to fix this, or apply the shadow to a more specific component.